# Finding trouble with replacing %index% in Xpaths (selenium scraper)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to write a simple web scraping bot that looks for prices and models of phones in the internet, however I am having a terrible time with `Xpaths` containing %index% (in order to replace it), and I can't ask for help as no one in my work team knows how to code.

```
if "%INDEX%" in base_name_xpath:
        index = 1
        while True:
            name_xpath = base_name_xpath.replace("%INDEX%", str(index))
            price_xpath = price_xpath.replace("%INDEX%", str(index))

            phone_models = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, name_xpath)
            phone_prices = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, price_xpath)

            if not phone_models:
                break  # Exit the loop if no more models are found

            for model, price in zip(phone_models, phone_prices):
                name = model.text.strip()
                name = clean_model_name(name)
                price_text = price.text.strip()
                if "Desde" in price_text:
                    price = price_text.split(" ")[1].strip()
                else:
                    price = price_text

                maker = next((maker for maker in makers if maker in name), "Other")

                scraped_data.append((maker,name, price))

            index += 1
```

This is the part of the function which reads the `xpaths` for indexed `xpaths`

and this is a sample of the text it receives:

I already tried with `ChatGPT` but as it cant access the internet it is basically useless to help me solve this.